# How can i deactivate the apache built in httpd web server on MAC ?

Tags: apache-2.4

When i starting mine MAC and got to the browser to localhost , i got the localhost output "It Working" from apache . 
After typing the command `sudo apachectl stop`, the server I THINK is stopped and after trying to go to localhost i got `localhost refused to connect`. BUT! When i open a new tab on the browser (Chrome) and go to localhost i got again "It Works" .. 
I can't understand that behaviour , can anybody explain to me ?
How can i deactivate the built in Apache server so it won't start again after i restart mine OS .. (I mean deactivate forever, because i want to use XAMP).. Need your help please i struggle with that 3 days already .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop Apache from starting every time you reboot, use

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This should stop Apache from restarting on its own on startup.